# Swapping Column in gridview c#

Tags: c#, gridview

Here i am doing swapping(interchanging) columns in grid-view. but my code not working

Here i am doing 3rd column moved to 2nd.

```
        var columnToMove = dataGridView2.Columns[2];
        dataGridView2.Columns.RemoveAt(2);
        dataGridView2.Columns.Insert(1, columnToMove);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change a column's position in a DataGridView set the DataGridViewColumn's [DisplayIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewColumn_DisplayIndex) property to the desired value:

```
 dataGridView2.Columns[2].DisplayIndex = 1;
```